# MKNetwork report a error run in Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I use cocoapods install MKNetwork. When I user this engine, Xcode report an error at this code:

ifndef __IPHONE_4_0

## error "MKNetworkKit uses features only available in iOS SDK 4.0 and later."

## endif

What's happened. In another project it works fine.

Comment: What's the deployment target set to?

Comment: Main project's targets is 8.0, Pod project's target is 8.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MKNetworkKit` appears to assume a pre-compile header importing Foundation. Since Xcode 6 you need to add the .pch file yourself and reference it in the relevant build settings for your target.

Comment: Think you! I have solved this problem with import Foundation where I using MKNetworkKit, I forget update my question. But why Xcode 6 removed .pch file?